# How to name a nested template in a templated base class?

Tags: c++, templates, base-class, name-lookup

In the following setup, how can I make it so that I can refer to the name `Bar` inside the derived class `Derived<T>`?

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    template <typename U> struct Bar { };
};

template <typename T> struct Derived : Foo<T>
{
    // what goes here?

    Bar<int> x;  // Error: 'Bar' does not name a type
};
```

I've tried `using Foo<T>::Bar;`, but that doesn't help. Is there any sort of `using` declaration that can make the name of a nested base template known to the derived class, so that I can keep the simple de­cla­ration `Bar<int> x`?

I know that I can say `typename Foo<T>::template Bar<int> x;`, but I have a lot of those cases and I don't want to burden the code needlessly with so much verbosity. I also have a lot of distinct "`int`s", so a `typedef` for each nested-template instance is not feasible, either.

Also, I cannot use GCC 4.7 at this point nor C++11, and would thus like a "traditional" solution without template aliases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11 you can use an alias template:

```
template <typename T> struct Derived : Foo<T>
{
  template<typename X> using Bar = typename Foo<T>::template Bar<X>;
  Bar<int> x;
};
```

**Edit**

The traditional solution is what you're already said, `typename Foo<T>:template Bar<int>`, or to emulate a "template typedef"

```
template <typename T> struct Derived : Foo<T>
{
  template<typename X>
    struct Bar
    { typedef typename Foo<T>::template Bar<X> type; };
  typename Bar<int>::type x;
};
```

One of the reasons for adding alias templates to the language is they support things which *can't* be expressed easily in C++03.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Unfortunately I don't have practical access to such a compiler, so I would like a "traditional" solution if possible :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB: What is "untraditional" about it?

Comment: @Nawaz: I can't use it in the project where I need this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `x` as `Foo<T>::Bar<int> x;` simply works for me.

Comment: I think, that shouldn't work! If it does, then I'm wondering how come. Maybe, the compiler has bug?

Comment: @Nawaz: Why? It compiles in Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2.

Comment: I don't want to change the declarations. I really *want* to be able to say just `Bar<int> x;`.

Comment: miloszmaki: `Bar` is a dependent type, so it shouldn't work without `typename`.

Comment: @miloszmaki : That's not a compiler, it's a (terrible) IDE that comes bundled with a downright ancient compiler (GCC 3.4.2).

Comment: @miloszmaki : Right -- as others have noted, your declaration is missing `typename` (because `Foo<T>` is a dependent type) and `template` (because `Bar<int>` is a template nested inside of a template). A conforming compiler would reject this declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    template <typename U> struct Bar { };
};

template <typename T> struct Derived : Foo<T>
{
    template<class W>
    struct Bar : public Foo<T>::template Bar<W> {

    };

    Bar<int> x;  
};
```

IDK if that's what you're looking for, but it does compile.

Comment: That's not exactly the same thing.  It's close, but even trivial things that should work if the types were the same don't in this case: `Derived<int> d; Foo<int>::Bar<int> y; d.x = y;`

Comment: That gives a nicer syntax than the "template typedef" in my answer, but it's worth noting that `Foo<T>::Bar<int>` and `Derived<T>::Bar<int>` are not actually the same type. That might not matter, but it could do in some cases e.g. templates or overloads that work with `Foo::Bar` might not match `Derived::Bar` and so the wrong overload gets used. (Edit: I see cvoinescu said the same thing, but more clearly.)

Comment: @cvoinescu Yes, it doesn't work in that case. However, if the class is used only internally inside `Derived`, then it will work(though I don't know if this is the case). I just wanted to point out a shorter syntax than the one used to declare a template typedef.